# How can I make a dialog box from jQuery show only after I hit a button?

Tags: jquery, dialog

This code is from the demo of modal confirmation on the jQuery site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        buttons: {
            'Yes': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'No': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="dialog" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<!-- Sample page content to illustrate the layering of the dialog -->
<div class="hiddenInViewSource" style="padding:20px;">
    <p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
    <form>
        <input value="text input" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" />checkbox<br />
        <input type="radio" />radio<br />
        <select>
            <option>select</option>
        </select><br /><br />
        <textarea>textarea</textarea><br />
    </form>
</div><!-- End sample page content -->

</div><!-- End demo -->

<div class="demo-description">

<p>Confirm an action that may be destructive or important.  Set the <code>modal</code> option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the <code>buttons</code> option.</p>

</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

Can anyone tell me how to make this show only after I hit a button? Right now it automatically shows in the page right after loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right or wrong, here's an example from a generic alert style dialog that I use:

Set up the dialog (in document ready):

```
$("#generic-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

And open the dialog (after some event):

```
$("#generic-dialog")
   .text("Status updated successfully.")
   .dialog("option", "title", "Your Status").dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the button to the page and add the code to the click event of the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            overlay: {
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                    opacity: 0.5
            },
            buttons: {
                    'Yes': function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'No': function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
            }
      });
   });
  });
</script>
```

and in HTML

```
<input type='button' value="click" id="button"/>
```

Comment: I was mere *seconds* too slow... +1, and my answer removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#btnTest").click(function() {
       $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    })
```

That should open the dialog you have defined - attaches the dialog open function to click event of button

Oh - and set `autoOpen: false` on the dialog setup properties :)